# Java string regex matches fails with linebreak?

Tags: java, android, regex

```
StringBuilder testSB = new StringBuilder();
String testString = "error 1:";
int times = 0;
while(times<=10){
    testSB.append(testString +"\n");
    times++;
}

String testResponse  = "error 1:";
String realResponse = testSB.toString();

Log.i("REAL", String.valueOf(realResponse.matches(".*error.*")));
Log.i("TEST", String.valueOf(testResponse.matches(".*error.*")));
```

The "real" string does not match, while the "test" string does. If I remove `+"\n"` from the while block, it matches regexp. I thought `.*` would apply for new line as well?

Comment: Linebreak is usually not part of `.` in regular expressions. You usually need to tell the regex engine specifically to include them. The convenience method `matches()` in the String class will not allow you to do that however. You will most likely need to build a `Pattern` and create a `Matcher` from it. There you can set the proper flag to achieve this.

Comment: @Till: The inline modifier, `(?s)`, can be used in this case (as mentioned in pap's answer).

Answer (score 6):

`.` does not match newline by default, but if you add the `(?s)` switch at the beginning of your regexp, it will.

Comment: to match `foo` in a String with new lines I had to use `"(?s).*foo(?s).*"`, that is to say I had to put it before each `.` character.

Answer (score 1):

Whether `.` matches line terminators depends on if `MULTILINE` mode is activated.
See the java documentation for [java.util.regex.Pattern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE).

Comment: It's `DOTALL` mode you're thinking of, not `MULTILINE`.  These modes should never have existed, and their names have always sucked, but at least Java changed the equally-confusing name "single-line" to the somewhat-self-explanatory "DOTALL".